# Prestashop 1.6.1.0 - copied default theme's navbar doesn't work

Tags: themes, prestashop

Hi I want to create custom theme using default-bootstrap so I copied whole folder, rename and then I made all changes in CSS.

I install my theme via backend, deleted all cache files and theme seems to working but there is issue with top navbar - it isn't look like as in default-bootstrap, check this:

Default's nav: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGY18.png

My nav: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0U9O.png

Any ideas why nav isn't lok like default?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

did you check your css + code for typos? That might be the case :)

try this:
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options